# Описание активности меток "в этом году", "месяце",

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

В описании меток под каждой меткой описана её активность - сколько вопросов задано за последний год, месяц, неделю... Но сформулированы эти периоды как "в этом году" (в 2017?!), в этом месяце, на этой неделе. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера возьмём модераторские метки, они хорошо видны, и если отсортировать вопросы по сроку - вывести за последний месяц - то будет видно, что имеется в виду именно последний месяц как время с сегодняшнего числа предыдущего месяца по сегодняшний день, а не текущий календарный месяц январь. Поправьте меня голосованием против вопроса, если я ошибаюсь, а если нет - давайте исправим описание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновил переводы с учетом [ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4505/176217), должно стать доступно на сайте после следующей сборки (больше чем `rev 2017.1.27.24839`).

Answer (score 3):

Например, так звучит тоже неоднозначно, но хотя бы мы убираем слово "этот", которое сбивает с толку.

```
{I} задано за неделю,  {J} за месяц, {K} - за год
```

Comment: Кстати, этот вариант согласуется со [статистикой из очереди проверок](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeJWa.png).

Answer (score -1):

Давайте оставим как есть, это не очень важная информация, а подобрать хорошее описание не получается.